# Node.js command prompt error ENOENT, stat C:\Users\student\AppData\Roaming\npm

Tags: windows, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to run an 'npm install' through my Node.js command prompt. After reading other forums I have tried running the prompt as administrator and creating an npm folder manually as suggested. I am getting the same error. Is there anybody that has encountered this issue or knows why this error is occuring? I am running this on Windows 7. Thanks!

Comment: does the folder exist? can run `dir C:\Users\student\AppData\Roaming\npm` and it says it exists? is it a **folder**

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the actual directory...when I in \student\ there is no AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: well there you go. make those dirs